# PDO::FETCH_COLUMN | PDO::FETCH_GROUP On Three columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

We can fetch the city_id and temp columns with  `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN | PDO::FETCH_GROUP`  something like these

```
 city_id      temp   date
   1          24.3    2017-12-03
   1          35.2    2017-11-26
   1          24.4    2017-11-19
   1          28.0    2017-11-12
   2          4.0     2017-12-03
   2          2.0     2017-11-26
   2          6.0     2017-11-19
   2          7.0     2017-11-12
   .
   .

 $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT `city_id`,`temp` FROM cities");
 $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN | PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

`$rows`  will be like this

```
[
  1 => [24.3,35.2,24.4,28.0],
  2=>  [4.0,2.0,6.0,7.0],
   ....
  ]
```

But is it possible somehow to get an associative multidimensional array in which will represent all the three columns .  Something like this

```
 $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT `city_id`,date,`temp` FROM cities");
 $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(What should be here? so that);
```

`$rows` should be like this

```
 [
  1 => [2017-12-03 => 24.3, 2017-11-26=>35.2, 2017-11-19=>24.4, 2017-11-12=>28.0],
  2=>  [2017-12-03 => 4.0, 2017-11-26=>2.0, 2017-11-19=>6.0, 2017-11-12=>7.0],
   ....
  ]
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [https://eval.in/916699](https://eval.in/916699). I don't know if it's possible in `fetchAll`, but you can parse it yourself as shown..

Comment: you can use PDO::FETCH_GROUP, though format won't be exactly the same but close

Comment: @FirstOne thanks, if it is not possible with fetchall() i can definitely use your solution, but let's wait to see if someone can do this  with fetchAll()